# Android MVP Where should i have a TextWatcher

Tags: java, android, android-mvp

I currently have my `TextWatchers` implemented on my view file (activity.java). However should they be in the presenter, since the presenter is the one who decided what to do after a user input, or is it wise to keep them where they are?

Comment: They'll have some logic on them, so I'd say they should go to the Presenter and then be accessible on the view. I'm more of an mvvm user though, so I can't answer with certainty.

Comment: Exactly! Because they have some logic on them i was wondering if they should be in the presenter. Also i didn't know about mvvm so i'll check it out, thanks :)

Comment: The Presenter should not know Android so I would not put it there. If you have logic then you can call the Presenter from the View informing the Presenter about the event that happened. Isn't this what you do for onClick listener? If you use MVI you send an "intent" to the Presenter or ViewModel

Comment: Yeah that makes more sense. I call a few methods from the presenter inside my view. I think i will switch to just calling a method from the presenter and then it decides what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two sides to your problem:

- on one hand the the **TextWatcher** is definitely part of the Android UI and since the **Presenter** should not know anything about Android specific code the **Watcher** should be part of the view
- on the other hand the **TextWatcher** needs to handle the incoming events and apply business logic to it, and since the **View** should be es dumb as possible the **Watcher** should be part of the **Presenter**

To fix this problem, my suggestion would be to keep the **Watcher** in the **View**, but only redirect it's incoming events to the **Presenter**:

```
class TextWatcher(presenter: MVPWatcherInterface) : ParentTextWatcher {

  private val presenterInterface: WeakReference<MVPWatcherInterface> = WeakReference(presenter)

  override fun onSomeTextEvent(){
    presenterInterface.get()?.onWatcherEventSomeTextEvent()
  }
}
```

To implement this, you have to define **MVPWatcherInterface** and implement it in your **Presenter** and pass it to the **TextWatcher** when you create it in the **View**. This allows you to handle all your business logic inside **onWatcherEventSomeTextEvent** inside your **Presenter**.

That way the code is clean and separated according to MVP rules :)

*(as a side note: the watcher I proposed uses a **WeakReference** to keep the **MVPWatcherInterface** -> I would highly recommend to implement it that way, so that your code won't generate any leaks by preventing the **Presenter** from being garbage collected)*